# After installing Homestead I get "No input file specified" in the browser. How can I access my laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

I think I finally got homestead installed on my laptop! Now, I am trying to view my laravel project in the browser.

When I open "dev.app" in the browser I get a message that say "No input file specified." which I think means that my homestead is working but the laravel project is not there/setup.

I have created a folder called Projects on my local laptop (i.e. ~/Projects). Then from inside of it i executed this command

laravel new dev

But I still get the same error message in the browser i.e. "No input file specified." I have also tried to open this link "dev.app"/dev" but I still get the same message.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is the content of my Homestead.yaml file

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: dev.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Additional, when I execute the following 2 commands in order

```
cd ~/Projects
ls
```

I see the following directories dev homestead

What should I do to see my project when I go to dev.app ? Do I need to do anything from my Ubuntu VM or I should be able to edit the files directly in located on ~\Projects\dev" from my laptop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Add an entry in `/etc/hosts` on your local machine

   ```
   192.168.10.10 dev.app
   ```
2. Correct the path to the public folder in the sites section of your `Homestead.yaml`

   ```
   sites:
       - map: dev.app
          to: /home/vagrant/Code/dev/public
   ```

Comment: It worked! thank you so much. I had to do `vagrant halt`  and then `vagrant up --provision` after the changes

Comment: @MikeA Great! I'm glad it all worked out for you. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too and @Mike, Thanks for highlighting the part where one has to "vagrant provision" after the changes, I had the corect configurations but was not provisioning!!

Comment: Worked for me after `vagrant up --provision`