# "No input file specified." when running Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I've installed Laravel Homestead and edited my host file but when I visit the specified URL in my browser I get the message "No input file specified." after running "vagrant up" in terminal. My initial guess is something's incorrect in the Homestead.yaml file but I can't see what.

I'm running Mac OS and my VM is a VirtualBox one. All my websites are in a folder called "Sites" which is a direct child of the OS user, so *Username/Sites*. The path of my Homestead folder is also in there like this: _Username/Sites/_homestead".

In the Homestead.yaml file I set my 'folder' to `map: ~/Sites` - that should mean when I visit the specified URL in the browser I get a list of folders (all of my websites), right? Or at least that was the result I'm expecting.

If I type `~Sites/` in my browser address bar I do see a list of folders so the location is correct. It redirects to file:///Users/USERNAME/Sites/

Before I run `vagrant up` 'username.dev' will not work when typed in the address bar, afterwards it does. So I assume that's all correct as it does pick it up.

This is the contents of my Homestead.yaml file for reference:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: username.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Can anyone see what's wrong or advise on what else is could be?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have to specify a specific folder, but if you want to switch quickly between your different projects you can map to multiple directories in the homestead.yaml file like that:

```
sites:
    - map: firstProject.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/firstProject/public

    - map: secondProject.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/secondeProject/public
```

You executed the command `vagrant up --provision` and still the same output?
I found similar questions which might help you here :
[Using Laravel Homestead: 'no input file specified'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274387/using-laravel-homestead-no-input-file-specified) and [After installing Homestead I get "No input file specified" in the browser. How can I access my laravel project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642890/after-installing-homestead-i-get-no-input-file-specified-in-the-browser-how-c)

Comment: Yeah I still get the same message after running the commands. 

And that's with 'folders' map: `~/Sites` to: `/home/vagrant/Code` and then 'sites' to map: `test.dev` to `/home/vagrant/Code/actual-folder-name-within-Sites/public` and it still didn't work. That folder I used does have an `index.php` and `index.html` in the root too.

Maybe I need to look at a new approach. At my old company I could boot up a VMWare VM which was Ubuntu and that'd let me view the URL as a list of folders and treat them all as though they were in a server environment.

Comment: In one answer I saw that somewone was updating the wrong Homestead.yaml file after he ran the `init.sh` bash command.
`Homestead.yaml file will be placed in the ~/.homestead hidden directory:`
It happend to me once maybe it is the case for you too.

Comment: That's interesting, I was editing the file where I installed it `Sites/_homestead/Homestead.yaml`. However I can't actually see a `.homestead` folder anywhere and I've turned on hidden files by using Terminal.

Comment: Out of interest, I'm now trying to set this up on a project folder with a very basic setup (no database etc). My question is should Homestead work if there's no `index.php`. I have a static website I thought I'd test this on, should it pick up `index.html` as well and use that?

Answer (score 0):

if the folder Username/Sites contains different site folders, try to map the URL to: `/home/vagrant/Code/yourSiteFolderName/public`

and run `vagrant reload --provision` or `vagrant up --provision` to reload the configuration

Comment: Yeah I basically have a folder called “Sites” and that has lots of sub-folders which are individual projects (websites) So could The mapped URL be `/home/vagrant/Code/Sites/public ` or must it be a specific sub-folder. I work on all these projects regularly so ideally I wanted to display a list in the browser and have homestead work on all of them - or is that not possible? Sorry if I’ve misunderstood!

Comment: Just to confirm I tried changing adding `yourSiteFolderName`, `Sites` and an actual folder name within the `Sites` folder but still no luck getting it working. I also tried making the URL point towards `Sites/projectname` which has an `index.php` file in the root but I still get the same error. :/

Answer (score 0):

For me after hours of searching I realized I had a capitalization error :(

```
   - map: C:/Users/jason/Code/blog
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/blog

sites:
    - map: blog.test
      to: /home/vagrant/***code***/blog/public
```

Code was code in the sites to: section.

So just an caution to everyone to check for the simplest errors first ;)